# Axis2 client creation from eclipse forbidden exception

Tags: exception, client, apache-axis

I have created webservice client based on this link http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html
I do realize that i am using WSDL1.1 specification.

From my WSDL i have the following serivce part(removed the xml tags as i  was not able to paste in SO)

service name="BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYService"
    documentation SAP Service BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAY via SOAP  documentation
    port name="BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYPortType" binding="s0:BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBinding"
        soap:address location="http://********:8000/sap/bc/soap/rfc"
    port
 service

Following is my client 
BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYService locator = new BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYServiceLocator();
            URL urlLocation;
            urlLocation = new URL("http://********:8000/sap/bc/soap/rfc");

```
        System.out.println(locator.getBAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYPortTypeAddress());

        BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBindingStub sapStub = new BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBindingStub(urlLocation,locator);

        sapStub.setUsername("****");
        sapStub.setPassword("*****");

        sapStub.BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAY("1");
```

I am getting the following error 
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (403)Forbidden
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  403
This service requires client certificate for authentication procedure.
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:403

(403)Forbidden
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at functions.rfc.sap.document.sap_com.BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBindingStub.BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAY(BAPI_CUSTOMER_DISPLAYBindingStub.java:234)
    at functions.rfc.sap.document.sap_com.SAPClient.main(SAPClient.java:33)

Any help is appreciated. My intention is to consume services with any java technologies.
This is Urgent.